# Doctrine using table name order

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I created a table named `order`. (Yes, bad choice I see). If I make a @OneToMany relation I get a mysql syntax error because Doctrine does not write the name in "`". Can't believe it...

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [enable quote_identifier with doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/configuration/en#identifier-quoting)

Comment: Also the first Google hit on searching "doctrine backticks".

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using Doctrine2. There you can solve it by using @Table(name="`order`"). See
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

Answer (score 5):

I had to use:
     @ORM\Table(name=" `order` ")

And yes, I had to include the spaces between the quotes and the backtics.  Very strange behavior.